# How would I have a video fill the screen without stretching (using Chewie or similar)?

Tags: flutter, video, dart, exoplayer

As the title says, is it possible to have a video fill the screen without visible stretching? If so, how would I do this with chewie?

Link to chewie: https://pub.dev/packages/chewie

**Problem**: 
[image]

The player fills the screen but the video is stretched because I've used MediaQuerys, but I don't know any other way to change the size of the player other than provide an aspectratio. I need to preserve the video's aspectratio but also have the video fit the screen.

**My current code**:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class MyVideoPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  final String path;

  MyVideoPlayer({Key key, @required this.path}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyVideoPlayerState createState() => new _MyVideoPlayerState();
}

class _MyVideoPlayerState extends State<MyVideoPlayer> {
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
  ChewieController _chewieController;
  Future<void> _future;
  TargetPlatform _platform;

  Future<void> initVideoPlayer() async {
    await _videoPlayerController.initialize();
    setState(() {
      print(_videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio);
      _chewieController = ChewieController(
        aspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/ MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
        autoPlay: false,
        looping: false,
        // showControls: false,
        materialProgressColors: ChewieProgressColors(
          playedColor: Colors.red,
          handleColor: Colors.blue,
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          bufferedColor: Colors.lightGreen,
        ),
        // placeholder: Container(
        //   color: Colors.grey,
        // ),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // _controller = VideoPlayerController.network('https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_20mb.mp4');
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(File(widget.path));
    _future = initVideoPlayer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        platform: _platform ?? Theme.of(context).platform,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _future,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return _videoPlayerController.value.initialized
                  ? Chewie(
                    controller: _chewieController,
                  )
                  : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: You are going to have to explain what "chewie" is since there is no tag for it.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's a plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/chewie It wraps google's video_player plugin which uses exoplayer and provides material design controls.

Comment: any solution... please

Comment: **[64 votes]** Use this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57077639/how-to-boxfit-cover-a-fullscreen-videoplayer-widget-with-specific-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 5):

```
    // an arbitrary value, this can be whatever you need it to be
    double videoContainerRatio = 0.5;

    double getScale() {
      double videoRatio = _videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio;
     
      if (videoRatio < videoContainerRatio) {
      ///for tall videos, we just return the inverse of the controller aspect ratio
        return videoContainerRatio / videoRatio;
      } else {
        ///for wide videos, divide the video AR by the fixed container AR
        ///so that the video does not over scale

        return videoRatio / videoContainerRatio;
      }
    }
```

1. Place an AspectRatio as high as you can in your widget tree, possibly directly above Chewie. This will determine the bounds of the video.

   ```
   AspectRatio(
     aspectRatio: videoContainerRatio,
     child: Chewie(...),
   )
   ```
2. Wrap *Chewie* in a Stack().
3. Now wrap your Chewie in a new AspectRatio and set its ratio to the _videoPlayerController aspect ratio:

   ```
   AspectRatio(
     aspectRatio: videoContainerRatio,
     child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController ,
            child: Chewie(...),
          ),
      ]
   ),
   ```
4. Now wrap the new AspectRatio in a Transform.scale() like this:

   ```
   Transform.scale(
     scale: getScale(),
     child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController ,
        child: Chewie(...),
     ),
   );
   ```

Comment: can't it be any simpler?

Answer (score 0):

I think its because your video just doesn't fit right into the width and height of your screen aspect ration. If you just use

```
aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
```

you will see the width and height of your video.

You could maybe wrap the Chewie in a Container with a fixed height/width and play with the aspect ration. You will need to stretch it to fit your entire screen i guess.

Comment: That is the correct way to do aspect ratio, however as far as that goes I could not find a solution for it to fill screen without using another plugin. (and not cropping horizontally) It is a similar issue to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49946153/flutter-camera-appears-stretched.           The plugin flick_video_player seems to account for device height and width and preserve aspect ratio.