# How to boxfit cover a VLC player video in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, vlc

I have been using the video_player but would like to switch to using the VLC player.

I had originally used this answer to display a video in cover mode

[How to BoxFit.cover a fullscreen VideoPlayer widget with specific aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57077639/how-to-boxfit-cover-a-fullscreen-videoplayer-widget-with-specific-aspect-ratio)

Is there a way to do this with vlc and remove the black bars around my video?

Thanks